# Error err_http2_protocol_error when making request with Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape this website 'https://web.trf3.jus.br/consultas/internet/consultareqpag'. The idea is very simple, I'll solve the captcha manually then my script will scrape all the information I need. The problem is that after I click 'pesquisar' (search) I get an error: err_http2_protocol_error.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome()
url = "https://web.trf3.jus.br/consultas/internet/consultareqpag"
driver.get(url)

# Solve captcha manually

driver.find_element(By.ID, "CpfCnpj").send_keys('05325542000158')
driver.find_element(By.ID, "pesquisar").click()
```

For now, I'm using Jupyter Notebook, so I can have time to solve the captcha before running the rest of the code. When the button is clicked I get the following error: [image]

How can I fix this issue? When I access the website manually everything runs as it should without any error.

Comment: Are you pausing the script to allow the manual captcha solving?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes. Right now I'm using Jupyter Notebook, so I start the webdriver in one cell, solve the captcha manually then run the second cell:

That's the second cell code, all the code above that is in the first cell:

driver.find_element(By.ID, "CpfCnpj").send_keys('05325542000158')
driver.find_element(By.ID, "pesquisar").click()

Comment: start chrome with `--disable-http2` flag. it resolved the issue for me, you can try.